# Identifying a graphics card

Tags: drivers, video, graphics-card

How do I determine the make and model of a graphics card installed in a Dell Desktop?

Belarc Advisor doesn't identify anything, and the model, a Dell Optiplex 780, has 5 different models to choose driver downloads for on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.hwinfo.com/

is best

Comment: Thanks.  It's hard to tell which downlink is an advertisement for some other driver utility, and which link is the HWINFO program.  It did identify the model which I had just installed drivers for (as a guess), so I hope it is not reading software, but hardware.

Answer (score 1):

you can use gpu-z freeware utility for this http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/

Answer (score 0):

I like using [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy). From their site:

> Speccy is an advanced System Information tool for your PC. Need to find out what's inside your computer? No problem! Speccy will give you all the information you need.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Is it good now?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555148). This will give you a prompt command to type in to get your graphic card details.

Comment: Thanks.  I might have to get C3-PO or R2-D2 to decipher the output.  :P

Comment: The output is simply 00IBM VGA Compatible BIOS.  Are you sure it is not identifying the software?